# Missing 'alg' in jwtSecurityToken header

Tags: asp.net-core, bearer-token, .net-8.0

When i am going to validate jwt token not decode not returning 'alg' and always invalidated the token validation. By default Validating in **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt**

Exception:

```
IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'Y-aoLdlxdepu_g1odJVOn_g-FlaitSghcGfrV1vSuxg'. , KeyId: 
    '. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '0'. 
    Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. 
    Exceptions caught:
     'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAlgorithmException: IDX10696: The algorithm 'Null' is not in the user-defined accepted list of algorithms.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had updated the package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`  from `7.2.0` to `7.4.1` and it works.